# How to display bootsrap 4 modal after success ajax Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

```
export function _UserSignUp(data) {
dispatcher.dispatch({
    type:'Loader',
    showLoader: true
})
data = JSON.stringify(data);
let actualurl = BASE + url;
Api._callAPI(actualurl, 'POST', data, (type, dt) => {
    if (type == 'success') {
        $("#successRegistration").modal('show');
    }
});
}


<div className="modal fade in" id="successRegistration">
<div className="modal-dialog popupbox">
    <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-body">
            <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                      <h3 className="alert_txt">{popupstatus == "success" ? "Registered Successfully" : null}</h3>
                    <h3 className="alert_txt">{popupstatus == "failure" ? popupresponse : null}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="modal-footer">
            <div className="row">
                <a href="/" className="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-simple float-right hidden-xs m-l-10" >Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon.png">
 <title>Individual Portal</title>
 <link href="css/style.custome.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

<body class="skin-megna fixed-layout">
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am having an ajax call on successAJax call i was trying to call a modal, after success call also i am unable to open the modal

I am getting an error `$ is not defined` I already have script in index.html for jquery still i am unable to open the model, Is this the correct way to do, or is there any other alternate way.

Comment: Are you using pure javascript or some framework?

Comment: Haven't you included Bootstrap CSS? Try to wrap your function in [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: @LovleshPokra react-flux

Comment: @rmalviya $(...).modal is not a function
I tried like this 
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#successRegistration").modal('show');
      });

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     $(document).ready(function() { 
          $("#successRegistration").modal('show'); 
     });
```